# Lookup every character in string and replace with character from another string

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, query-optimization

I have a table with two string type columns named IL and CL. I have to compare both the strings character by character and wherever there is a question mark in column CL string, I have to replace it with the character found in the other column (IL), in the exact same position.

For example, the CL string after comparing with IL and replacing the question marks would be the New CL as shown below

| CL | IL | NEW CL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ???-123201-000000-000-??? | 104-234561-644221-123-947 | 104-123201-000000-000-947 |

I have the below code working, where there is a `while` loop inside of a `cursor` going through each character of the string, concatenating into a new string, and then doing an update at the end with the new value. However, performance with this piece of code is horribly slow as the table has 100K+ records and it's looping through each row 25 time (string length). I am looking to see if perhaps there is a way to rewrite this logic set based for performance improvement.

```
declare CharC insensitive cursor for 
  select ID, IL, CL
  from AcctStrings
  where CL like '%?%' 

open CharC
fetch next from CharC into @ID, @IL, @CL
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin

    set @NewCL = ''
    set @i = 1 

    while @i <= 25 begin
      set @TestChar = substring(@CL,@i,1)
      set @OtherChar = substring(@IL,@i,1)

      if (@TestChar = '?') begin
        set @NewCL = @NewCL + @OtherChar 
      end 
      else 
        set @NewCL = @NewCL + @TestChar

      set @i = @i + 1
    end

    update AcctStrings
      set CL = @NewCL
    where ID = @ID
  end

  fetch next from CharC into @ID, @IL, @CL
end
deallocate CharC
```

Comment: What version of SQL_SERVER are you using? Run the command `select @@version`. One possible answer may involve using `GENERATE_SERIES()`, `SUBSTRING()`, `CASE`, and `STRING_AGG()`. Some of these functions are recent additions to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using SQL Server 2022, you can try the following:

```
UPDATE AcctStrings
SET CL = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(N.NewC, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY S.Value)
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(CL)) S
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(CL, S.value, 1) AS C) O
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN O.C = '?' THEN SUBSTRING(IL, S.value, 1) ELSE O.C END AS NewC) N
)
WHERE CL LIKE '%?%'
```

The above uses a subquery to break the `CL` string down into individual characters, apply the transform (when needed), and then reconstruct the updated string.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XevPCFBT) for a demo.

Results (with some additional test data):

| CL | IL | NewCL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `???-123201-000000-000-???` | `104-234561-644221-123-947` | `104-123201-000000-000-947` |
| `111-222222-333333-444-555` | `xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xxx` | *null* |
| `?????????????????????????` | `123-654321-123456-456-789` | `123-654321-123456-456-789` |

The *null* value indicates that no `NewCL` value was calculated, because the original value contained no "?"s.

**Addendum:**

For SQL Server 2019, the `GENERATE_SERIES()` function is unavailable, but there are several alterative techniques available for generating a number sequence - A `VALUES` subselect, `ROW_NUMBER()` applied to a sufficiently large row source, or a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression).

The following uses a recursive CTE to generate a number sequence, that is then limited to the CL string length in the `WHERE` clause. The remaining logic is the same.

```
;WITH Series AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.Value + 1 AS Value
    FROM Series S
    WHERE S.Value < 99 -- At least the maximum expected length of CL
)
UPDATE AcctStrings
SET CL = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(N.NewC, '') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY S.Value)
    FROM Series S
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(CL, S.value, 1) AS C) O
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN O.C = '?' THEN SUBSTRING(IL, S.value, 1) ELSE O.C END AS NewC) N
    WHERE S.Value <= LEN(CL)
)
WHERE CL LIKE '%?%'
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D8Bmqd1R).

For 2016, we need to fall back to the old `FOR XML PATH('')` technique.

```
...
SET NewCL = (
    SELECT (
        SELECT N.NewC as [text()]
        FROM Series S
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(CL, S.value, 1) AS C) O
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN O.C = '?' THEN SUBSTRING(IL, S.value, 1) ELSE O.C END AS NewC) N
        WHERE S.Value <= LEN(CL)
        ORDER BY S.value
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
)
...
```

Since we are not inserting separators, the `STUFF()` can be omitted from this use case. Normally, the expression being concatenated defaults to a `text()` element (plain text), but since it is a direct column reference, an explicit `AS [text()]` is needed to avoid the value being formatted as `<NewC>x</NewC>`. The use of `, TYPE` and `.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')` is best practice to avoid character encoding issues.

See [this 2016 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KUWDxPPu).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using SQL Server 2019. Is there any other way for 2019 or older versions?

Comment: I've updated my answer above for SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I did not know about these functions `STRING_AGG()` or `GENERATE_SERIES()`. I was testing your example and I found out that I have to also support SQL 2016 along with 2019 with this script. I think I have to use `STUFF` and `XML PATH` since the other functions aren't available prior to SQL 2017.

Comment: I've updated the above answer again for 2016.